# intermediate layer error tensorflow with pre-trained resnet50

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am trying to carry out a transfer learning with resnet50, but not understanding why it is giving me an error. I tried to do the same thing with Mobilenet and it works.The pc I am using is not connected to the internet and therefore I downloaded the weights separately.
This is my code

```
def resnet50(image_size,num_classes,num_channels, dense_size, drop_prec, include_top, preweights):
    if preweights:
        if include_top:
            path = os.path.join('weights_pre_trianed', 'resnet50_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels.h5')
            res = applications.ResNet50(include_top=include_top,
                                                      input_shape=(image_size[0], image_size[1], num_channels),
                                                      weights=path)
            x = res.output
            preds = Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')(x)
            model = Model(inputs=res.input, outputs=preds)
            for layer in model.layers[:143]:
                layer.trainable = False
            for layer in model.layers[143:]:
                layer.trainable = True
            return model
```

i get the following error

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Invalid argument: Computed output size would be negative: -227 [input_size: 56, effective_filter_size: 512, stride: 2]
     [[{{node res3a_branch1/convolution}}]]
     [[Mean/_2259]]
  (1) Invalid argument: Computed output size would be negative: -227 [input_size: 56, effective_filter_size: 512, stride: 2]
     [[{{node res3a_branch1/convolution}}]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored.
```

I use tensorflow 1.15 and keras 2.3.1.
My images are grayscale and size 224x224 a 3 channels
why am i getting this error?

EDIT1: node res3a_branch1 is layer number 45 Conv2D
EDIT2: I want a binary classification

Edit3:I tried as you suggested by the link, but now another error related to the model has appeared. I know I should be using a lambda layer but I don't know how.

```
    'node = layer._inbound_nodes[node_index] 
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_inbound_nodes'
```

this is my code after

```
 path=os.path.join('weights_pre_trianed',
'resnet50_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels_notop.h5')
 i = Input([None, None, 3], dtype='float32')
 x = applications.resnet50.preprocess_input(i)
 res = applications.ResNet50(include_top=include_top, weights=path)                                       
        
 x = res(x)
 x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
 preds = Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')(x)
 model = Model(inputs=i, outputs=preds)
 for layer in model.layers[:-2]:
        layer.trainable = False
 return model
```

Comment: Please do not use the comments for addingl info; edit & update your question instead. Also, please include explicitly your relevant **imports**.

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/applications/ResNet50 mentions that input_shape should not be specified if include_top is True, and IMPORTANTLY, this line "Note: each Keras Application expects a specific kind of input preprocessing. For ResNet, call tf.keras.applications.resnet.preprocess_input on your inputs before passing them to the model."

Comment: @jhso I tried as you suggested by the link, but now another error related to the model has appeared. I know I should be using a lambda layer but I don't know how. 'node = layer._inbound_nodes[node_index]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_inbound_nodes' '

Comment: Maybe update your question with these details?